# How to fix an error on django admin interface

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi i am using Django admin to work on some task. i have created a model and added project name. so whenever i am creating a project say 'project5' and adding details and if again i am creating another project with same name and same details it is being created. What i want is i do not want the project name created to be with same details. it should give error. Please let me know how to fix this.

Here below i have created a model with a class name and some fields.[image]
[image]

Modals.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    added_by = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("name", "users"))
```

Settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'
```

Comment: use `unique_together = ("name", "added_by")`. both should be the fields from same model. You were using "users" field which is not part of the Project model.

Comment: @Jarvis i am creating two different users. user 1 and user 2. one user cannot create project of same name again. but different user can have project of same name. even still i am able to create project of same name with the same user.

Comment: Did you perform migration after updating the `unique_together`?

Answer (score 0):

Its simple to answer

you just define that particular field with `unique = True`. you can read more about unique [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/)

Comment: Thanks, Also sir i have created different users who can further create project name. if user1 has created project1 i also want user2 to create project1. i mean same user cannot create project with same name but different users can create project with same name.Please let me know how to fix this sir.

Comment: in that case you define ```unique_together``` in model META and remove ```unique = True``` from the project name field

Comment: i have posted the code above and unique_together gives an error. 'unique_together' refers to the nonexistent field 'users'.

Comment: you can try: `unique_together = (("name", "added_by"), )`

Comment: This Worked!!! But when I create same project of same name it leads to IntegrityError at/admin/ instead it should give an error message on Django admin that this project already exists.

Answer (score 0):

In your model you need to say which field should be unique:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    jira_subdomain = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    # other fields
```

You could have more than one unique field. For more details take a look at
[django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.unique)

Comment: Thanks, Also sir i have created different users who can further create project name. if user1 has created project1 i also want user2 to create project1. i mean same user cannot create project with same name but different users can create project with same name.Please let me know how to fix this sir.

Comment: @SahilSuri Each model has a unique table in the database so if your Project model has a foreign key to User model so every project name could be unique between all users in this table. Also you could check the uniqueness of a project name in your view when try to grab data from your form and just before save() method. First you should make a query like this: project_check=Project.objects.filter(project_name="sample_name") if project_name==None it means it is unique so you could save it.